# mongo kafka connect source

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using kafka connect in order to read data from mongo and write them to kafka topic.

I am using the mongo kafka source connector.

I am getting the following error :

```
ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:115)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/ConnectionString
    at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.MongoSourceConfig.createConfigDef(MongoSourceConfig.java:209)
    at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.MongoSourceConfig.<clinit>(MongoSourceConfig.java:138)
    at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector.config(MongoSourceConnector.java:56)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.Connector.validate(Connector.java:129)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:282)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.putConnectorConfig(StandaloneHerder.java:188)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.ConnectionString
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 7 more
```

It seems that there is amising clas in the jar. In order to get the jar I used two different methods but I am gettng the same error. First I  used the download fro: the maven repository and then I clone the source code from the github repo and I build the jar by myself. I pushed the jar to the plugins.path. 
When I unzip the generated jar and go through the calsses I can't find the mentioned class: com.mongodb.ConnectionString

I used the following config files

worker.properties :

```
 rest.port=18083

# Set to a list of filesystem paths separated by commas (,) to enable class loading isolation for plugins
# (connectors, converters, transformations). The list should consist of top level directories that include 
# any combination of: 
# a) directories immediately containing jars with plugins and their dependencies
# b) uber-jars with plugins and their dependencies
# c) directories immediately containing the package directory structure of classes of plugins and their dependencies
# Note: symlinks will be followed to discover dependencies or plugins.
# Examples: 
# plugin.path=/usr/local/share/java,/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins,/opt/connectors,
plugin.path=/usr/share/java/plugins

internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
bootstrap.servers=127.0.0.1:9092
```

mongo-connector.properties:

```
name=mongo
tasks.max=1
connector.class =com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector
database=
collection=alerts
key.converter = org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter = org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter

topic.prefix=someprefix
poll.max.batch.size=1000
poll.await.time.ms=5000

# Change stream options
pipeline=[]
batch.size=0
change.stream.full.document=updateLookup
```

then I launched the connector by the following command :

```
/usr/local/kafka/bin/connect-standalone.sh worker.properties mongo-connector.properties
```

Any idea how to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place the connector's JAR file under `plugin.path` which in your case is `/usr/share/java/plugins`.

The instructions are already present in [Confluent's documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#installing-plugins):

> A Kafka Connect plugin is:
>
> an uber JAR containing all of the classfiles for the plugin and its
>   third-party dependencies in a single JAR file; or a directory on the
>   file system that contains the JAR files for the plugin and its
>   third-party dependencies. However, a plugin should never contain any
>   libraries that are provided by Kafka Connect’s runtime.
>
> **Kafka Connect finds the plugins using its plugin path**, which is a
>   comma-separated list of directories defined in the Kafka Connect’s
>   worker configuration. To install a plugin, place the plugin directory
>   or uber JAR (or a symbolic link that resolves to one of those) in a
>   directory listed on the plugin path, or update the plugin path to
>   include the absolute path of the directory containing the plugin.

Comment: @scalacode Have you restarted Kafka Connect after making these changes so that it is able to re-read the `plugins.path` content and load the connectors?

Comment: I chnaged the name of the connector , but this didn't work either

Comment: @scalacode Where is your connector's jar file located?

Comment: it is working now , I took the jar  from confluent not the official one in maven

Answer (score 0):

Im creating this answer as I tooksome time to find out the solution, as pointed out by scalacode, the easiest solution is to download the jar from confluent, not from maven.

https://www.confluent.io/hub/mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb